# SQLAlchemy arithmetic formula in where clause of update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to do an update with a simple arithmetic expression in the where clause:

```
def update_items(self, item_type, x, y):
    table = Items.__table__
    stmt = table.update().where(table.c.item_type == item_type,
                         x - table.c.delivered > y).values(available=False)

    with self.session_scope() as s:
        s.execute(stmt)
```

The problem seems to be with `x - table.c.delivered > y`. I am getting an error:

> TypeError: where() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: `where()` doesn't accept multiple conditions. You either need to chain (`.where(cond1).where(cond2)`) or use `and_` (`.where(and_(cond1, cond2))`